# Azure release pipeline to extract files from Artifact folder and copy to a target folder

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Copy files from artifacts to a folder

I am  using Azure Devops Deployment group job to copy some files to the server

The 2 steps I am following are 1. Stop a Windows service using Powershell  and looks OK

Then using CopyFiles  task to copy the files from the Artifacts location

- The artifcat is a zip file and the location is mapped correctly
- I have to unzip the contents of the zip file and move to the target folder
  Or move the zip file to the target folder and unzip the file contents after its copied

But the CopyFiles task is not copying any files [ I tried various combinations in Contents property to include zip extension etc but no luck]

Is any of the steps are missing or i am doing wrong? The screen shot of PIpeline is like below

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Based on your requirement, you need to unzip the contents of the zip file  and copy files.

I suggest that you can use [Extract files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/extract-files?view=azure-devops) to unzip the zip file.

In Copy files task, you don't need to specify a specific zip file in the source folder. You just need to specify the folder path where the files are located.

Here is an example: `$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)/_Data Cloud Service Live/service`

[image]